# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index' (python)

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm doing 'guess the word' on Python and I can't figure out this error.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index' (python)
```

It is giving me an error on the line `letterIndex=word.index(guess)`.

```
def checkLetter(word):

    blanks = '_' * len(str(word))
    print('Word: ', blanks)
    if str(guess) == str(letters):
        letterIndex = word.index(guess)
        newBlank = blanks[:letterIndex * 2] + guess + blanks[letterIndex * 2 + 1]
        print('Guess Corrrect')
```

Comment: You need to learn to read the error messages. It is telling you what went wrong exactly. `word` is an integer. Integers do not have the method `index`. So you go through your code and search for the place where you define `word` as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

From earlier when you cast word as a string, I presume that word is not a string. With that in mind, it may not have the index function. At the very least, you likely need to change that line to

```
letterIndex=str(word).index(guess)
```

Although I would raise questions on why a variable called word is an int.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'

The error message could hardly be more clear. It tells you that `word` is an `int` and has no attribute named `index`. Did you intend `word` to be a string? Or did you forget to convert it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

`word` variable is of `int` type , and `int` type does not have the `index` function.
Convert word to string type using `str()`:

```
letterIndex=str(word).index(guess)
```